# What does it mean that God's wrath is infinite and what is its relation to existence of life on other planets?

Tags: nature-of-god, church-history, extra-terrestrial-life, wrath-of-god

I heard on the first episode of Cosmos that astronomer [Giordano Bruno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giordano_Bruno) was punished because he believed there are other planets with life on them. The Roman inquisition sentenced him to execution because they thought this belief violated the fact that 'God's wrath is not eternal'.  I would be appreciate it if you provide me a resource to read about it, or give me an explanation. I am not Christian and this idea is so new to me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything exactly like this; but check the Wikipedia article on Galileo for something rather similar.

Comment: His name was Bruno.I saw it on Fox channel.the serial name was cosmos

Comment: Take a read of the Wikipedia article on [Giordano Bruno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giordano_Bruno). Then let us know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I read it but that didn't explain about this idea(exactly that didn't even mention it)

Comment: This is my guess : Can we say that if there is an infinite world with infinite wights then Jesus Christ couldn't recede God wrath with his Crucifixion?

Comment: @CoderInNetwork: It does mention it. It says `scholars emphasize that Bruno's astronomical views were at most a minor component of the theological and philosophical beliefs that led to his trial`. So the idea that he was sentenced because his belief violated the fact that 'God's wrath is not eternal' is probably an embellishment.

Comment: nice deduction @Flimzy although it seems that the serial tried to hold a relation between those two.

Comment: @CoderInNetwork: I haven't watched the show, although I'm downloading it now via torrent. I've heard it's good anyway... after I see that episode, maybe I can provide better insight into what they were talking about. Do you by chance remember which episode it was?

Comment: That was the first episode.I would be glad to know your idea about that.thank you

Comment: http://www.theguardian.com/science/the-h-word/2014/mar/14/cosmos-history-science-giordano-bruno-danger-heroes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the program, Bruno was found guilty

> of questioning the Holy Trinity and the divinity of Jesus Christ, of believing that God's wrath is not eternal, that everyone will be saved, of asserting the existence of other worlds.

To answer your first question, "What does it mean that God's wrath is infinite?" it appears, based on the quote from the program, that Bruno was a [universalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Universalism).  This was, and often still is by many Christians, considered a heresy.

The answer to your second question, "What is its relation to existence of life on other planets?" is that there is none. These were separate, distinct charges, unrelated to each other. There is no implication that the believing in other worlds is in any way related to the believing that God's wrath is not eternal.